# Setting a listener on a RatingBar is always called

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm using a RatingBar in my app and trying to set a listener on it when a user rates.

**xml**

```
<RatingBar
  android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:numStars="5" />
```

**Java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch_video);

    (...) //findViewById
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "on rating bar changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

However the listener ([setOnRatingBarChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar#setOnRatingBarChangeListener(android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener))) is always called when the activity starts, despite any physical interaction on it.

What could be my issue here?

Comment: There is a boolean `fromUser` which you can validate .. this is the default behavior of `Listener` same thing goes with `Spinner` ..

Comment: you can use onclicklistener of rating bar to achieve your functionality ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use like this - 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch_video);

    (...) //findViewById
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
if(fromUser){
            Toast.makeText(context, "on rating bar changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this using "fromUser" parameter in onRatingChanged function. If the value is true it means the rating was changed by user.